# How to force Chrome to show latest image changes on website

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser-cache

**EDIT: Please stop suggesting to clear the cache. That will obviously not solve anything for the users who may have visited the site before.**

---

I know how to force the browser to use the latest CSS version. This is not what I'm asking.
I also know how to clear the cached images on the browser. This is also not what I'm asking.
I also know this could be solved by changing the name of the image. I don't want to do that.

It surprises me not being able to find an answer to this issue anywhere since I came across this problem multiple times.

When replacing an image such as a logo that's on every page of an old website, you may want to simply replace the image without changing its name so you don't have to change the image name on every HTML page.

The problem is that Chrome continues to show the old version of that image no matter how many times you refresh the page.

It's the only browser I know that does this. It's incredibly annoying.

Isn't there a way to force Chrome to show this change, or even request Google to update the image that has been replaced?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on how you generate the pages on the server side. Please be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

ctrl shift i (to open the developers tool)
click network
check the disable cached data from the top of the window
or u can use the shortcut i think ctrl R (i am not sure of it) but using the developer tool ->network ->disabling cache then refreshing the page works fine 100%

Comment: Thanks. As I stated in my question: "I know how to clear the cached images on the browser. This is also not what I'm asking. "

Comment: this only disable cache for the page you are opening only, it doesn't delete cached files